# Calculating Number of Months between 2 dates

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, date

I have the following VB.NET Code:

```
Dim Date1 As New DateTime(2010,5,6)
Dim Date2 As New DateTime(2009,10,12)
Dim NumOfMonths = 0 ' This is where I am stumped
```

What I am trying to do is find out how many months are between the 2 dates. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose it depends on your definition of months, do you mean calendar months or groups of 30 days?

Comment: see also: `DateDiff()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.datediff

Comment: Why do you hate February? :-(

Comment: Here is the simple and short code in case, you still couldn't get the answer, see this
[POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820603/how-a-month-is-defined-in-the-rest-of-the-world) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820603/how-a-month-is-defined-in-the-rest-of-the-world

Answer (score 6):

Here's a method you could use:

```
Public Shared Function MonthDifference(ByVal first As DateTime, ByVal second As DateTime) As Integer
    Return Math.Abs((first.Month - second.Month) + 12 * (first.Year - second.Year))
End Function
```

like this:

```
Dim Date1 As New DateTime(2010,5,6)
Dim Date2 As New DateTime(2009,10,12)
Dim NumOfMonths = MonthDifference(Date1, Date2)
```

Comment: This will return the difference in the month number, but is that really the number of months difference between the two dates? e.g. It will return 1 if the dates are 30th Jun & 1st July of the same year.

Comment: Thanks, this also works for C#. @fivebob: Your way of seeing it, can't be answered, since months have different lengths, right?